Seed not germinating after 10 days of pregermination, any thoughts?
I pregerminated Scott's Turf Builder MAX seeds 10 days ago. I still haven't seen any germination. This seed consists of Kentucky blue grass and perennial rye grass. What could be the reason it's taking so long? From what I've seen in videos, they say it should start germinating by Day 5 or 6. I would appreciate any input. Thank you!

Whats your weather like?  How have you been treating the sod?  Did you check the expiry dates on the seeds?   How big an area [and if not big, did the birds get to it?
